# Is there a way to recover a document if the document has never been saved for Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-recovery, autosave

I unchecked the auto recover box by accident and in the middle of my calculations my computer crashed. Is there a way to recover the workbook I was working on when it crashed? I never got the chance to save it. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: if office or the PC crashed (instead of closing gracefully) there should be a temporary file of the last autosave, assuming you had the window open for more than 10 minutes. The tricky part is finding it, as it is likely deep in user temporary folders in %APPDATA%. I'd probably search by extension and create date to see if it turns up.

Comment: Thanks Frank but I never saved this workbook ever so auto recover is not an option. Will I still be able to look for the file if it was never saved at any point in time?

Comment: office saves documents by default every 10 minutes, so there may be a temp save file you don't know about. Office uses temp files for a number of reasons, and they are usually deleted when office closes gracefully, but if it crashed, there is likely one floating around somewhere in your %APPDATA%

Comment: Auto recover was disabled as soon as I began to work on the document.